# Problem in Twitter Api - Android

Tags: android, twitter

I am using the following link to integrate Twitter API into my application.

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/

Now when i run the code after setting up the SECRET KEY AND CONSUMER KEY on the emulator it runs fine. BUt when i run that application on mobile device it gives me Exception.

The Exception is:

```
Error during OAUth retrieve request token
Authorization failed (server replied with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not match.
  auth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:239)
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
 at com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask.doInBackground(OAuthRequestTokenTask.java:57)
 at com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.OAuthRequestTokenTask.doInBackground(OAuthRequestTokenTask.java:1)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:
```

Friends what should i do.? m Tottaly messed. n stucked.

Please Guide me any one.

Answer (score 0):

It worked just entering in Constants.java the Consumer key and Consumer secret, and pay

attention to give on twitter page, for Twitter Application also Write access: READ&WRITE.

By the way, I made the new application registration on developer site:

https://dev.twitter.com and i saw posted message on account on:

http://twitter.com. I got that black screen too with login errors first time because i had

just Read enabled, after giving also write it worked.

Anyway, if you did not succed, here is another link i found, with keys filled for a test

application and only to be replaced by yours:

http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/for-all-my-code-thirsty-frie nds-twitter.html

Hope this helps, Regards.